# How to render a custom "Note" component into the Scrollview of App.js in my react native app?

Tags: react-native, expo

**App.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import Note from './components/Note';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    noteArray: [ {date: "testdate", note: "testnote 1"} ],
    noteText: '',
  };

  addNote() {
    if (this.state.noteArray.length >= 0) {
      var d = new Date();
      this.state.noteArray.push({
        date: d.getFullYear() + '/' + (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate(),
        note: this.state.noteText,
      });
      this.setState({ noteArray: this.state.noteArray });
      this.setState({ noteText: '' });
    }
    // alert(this.state.noteText);
    console.log(this.state.noteArray);

  }
  deleteNote(key) {
   return;
  }

  render() {

    let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key) => {
     return (
        <Note
          key={key}
          keyval={key}
          valDate={val.date}
          valNote={val.note}

          deleteMethod={() => this.deleteNote(key)
          }
        />
      );
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.header}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>NOTER</Text>
        </View>

        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollview}>

        {notes}

        </ScrollView>

        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={this.addNote.bind(this)}
            style={styles.addButton}>
            <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            onChangeText={noteText => this.setState({ noteText })}
            value={this.state.noteText}
            placeholder=">> note"
            placeholderTextColor="#CD5C5C"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    alignContent: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderBottomWidth: 10,
    borderBottomColor: '#ddd',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    padding: 8,
    fontSize: 42,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor:"#ADFF2F"
  },
  headerText: {
    backGroundColor: '#FFC0CB',
    fontSize: 42,
    color: '#CD5C5C',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  scrollview: {
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: 500,
    backgroundColor:"#ADDD2F",
  },
  footer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    alignItems: 'center',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor:"#ADFF2F"
  },
  addButton: {
    width: 90,
    height: 90,
    borderRadius: 50,
    borderColor: '#F08080',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContents: 'center',
    elevation: 8,
    backgroundColor : "#F08080",
    marginBottom: -45,
    zIndex: 10,
  },
  addButtonText: {
    color: '#258',
    fontSize: 24,
    padding: 30,
  },
  textInput: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    color: '#fff',
    padding: 20,
    paddingTop: 46,
    backgroundColor: '#252525',
    borderTopColor: '#ededed',
  },
});
`
**Note.js**

`import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';


export default class Note extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.note}>

        <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.valDate}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.valNote}</Text>


        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>

        <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}>
        D
        </Text>

        </TouchableOpacity>


      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  note:{
    position:"relative",
    padding:20,
    paddingRight:100,
    borderBottomWidth:2,
    borderBottomColor:"#effded",

  },

  noteText:{
    paddingLeft:20,
    borderLeftWidth:10,
    borderLeftColor:"#E98B63",

  },

  noteDelete:{
    position:"absolute",
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItems:"center",
    backgroundColor:"#9983b9",
    padding:10,
    bottom:10,
    right:10,

  },

  noteDeleteText:{
    color:"white",
  },



});
```

`I am trying to render a custom "Note" component into the Scrollview of App.js in my react native app.

As can be seen into the logs, the data from Note Text is getting pushed into the array (please check the logs, there you'll find that) however my entire **Note Component** is not getting rendered as desired.

The link to my snack is: https://snack.expo.io/@vshiva2306/todoapp

Comment: This question is presently off-topic as it is not "self-contained". We need everything that the reader needs to see and know **in the question itself**, so that if the link dies, or if you modify it into a working state, the question will still be useful for future readers. Would you edit your question now? (Links to external code runners are OK, as long as they are supplemental).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot going on in your code, and without an image of what it is meant to look like it is hard to style.

There are a few changes you can make to your styles to get this to work, because the items are rendering you just can't see it.

You are missing a container style. Add the following to your StyleSheet.

```
container: {
  flex: 1
}
```

In your `styles.headerText` fix the property `backGroundColor` it should be `backgroundColor`

In your `styles.scrollview` remove the `marginBottom: 500`

In your `styles.addButton` fix the property `justifyContents` it should be `justifyContent`

In your `styles.footer` remove `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`

Here is a snack containing the changes that I made https://snack.expo.io/rkRhNrvX4, also here is a link to the diff between your `App.js` and mine https://www.diffchecker.com/fz4n3qkN

Here is what it renders out as

[image: rendered image]

There is a lot more that can be fixed in your app, but this should get you started.

Comment: Hey @Andrew, thanks for being a real savior. The code is working fine now, with some changes done by me. Now my next target is to save the data using AsyncStorage. Let's see how far do I go. :)